# tmpl() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

I am getting the error `tmpl() is not a function` in my jQuery 3.3.1 project. According to [this page](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates), templates should be part of the core, after version 1.5.

This is my HTML code:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script id="itemTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <td>${title}</td>
        <td><span class="fa fa-plus-square"></span>${amount}<span class="fa fa-minus-square"></span></td>
    </tr>
</script>

...

<table id="basket">
```

and this is my Javascript:

```
$("#itemTemplate").tmpl(item).appendTo("#basket");
```

I have searched the jQuery site, but couldn't find anything on templates.

Comment: That link also shows loading a separate template script and mentions the *"jQuery templates plugin"*. There is no such functionality in jQuery core

Comment: A better suggestion is use template scripts like handelbars.js or mustache.js or use a framework like angular, react or vue

Comment: @charlietfl from the page: "jQuery Templates will be included in the jQuery core library (the jQuery.js library) when jQuery 1.5 is released.". I guess that never came into being.

Comment: That is talking in the future and no it never happened and that template project also stopped being developed. The others I mentioned are more current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like jQuery no longer supports templates.

Quoting from the [jquery-tmpl](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl) repository on GitHub

> ## jQuery Templates plugin vBeta1.0.0
>
> jQuery Templates is no longer in active development, and will be superseded by [JsRender](http://github.com/borismoore/jsrender). See vBeta1.0.0 tag for released beta version. Requires jQuery version 1.4.2.
>
> Note: This is the original official jQuery Templates plugin. The project was maintained by the jQuery team as an official jQuery plugin. Since the jQuery team has decided not to take this plugin past beta, it has been returned to the principal developer's GitHub account (Boris Moore). For more information on the history of jQuery Templates, and the roadmap going forward, see [jQuery Templates and JsViews: The Roadmap](http://www.borismoore.com/2011/10/jquery-templates-and-jsviews-roadmap.html)

Answer (score 1):

Reading your link it seems that your forgot to add the `script` for the plugin, it is *not* a part of the core jQuery. [This is the official GitHub page](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl), where it states that it was discontinued:

> Note: This is the original official jQuery Templates plugin. The
>   project was maintained by the jQuery team as an official jQuery
>   plugin. Since the jQuery team has decided not to take this plugin past
>   beta, it has been returned to the principal developer's GitHub account
>   (Boris Moore).

But you can add the function with:

```
<script>http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js</script>
```